# Using lapply with Dates and the minus function

Tags: r, lapply

I have a vector of dates and a vector of number-of-days.

```
dates <- seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+10, by='day')
number.of.days <- 1:4
```

I need to get a list with an entry for each number-of-days, where each entry in the list is the dates vector minus the corresponding number-of-days, ie.,

```
list(dates-1, dates-2, dates-3, dates-4)
```

The defintion of `-` (`function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("-")`) indicates that its first and second arguments are `e1` and `e2`, respectively. So the following should work.

```
lapply(number.of.days, `-`, e1=dates)
```

But it raises an error.

> Error in `-.Date`(X[[i]], ...) : can only subtract from "Date" objects

Furthermore, the following *does* work:

```
lapply(number.of.days, function(e1, e2) e1 - e2, e1=dates)
```

Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: Unrelated to the topic, `Map` would be easier. `Map('-', list(dates), number.of.days)`

Comment: That's actually what I'm using now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
lapply(number.of.days, `-.Date`, e1=dates)
```

Part of the problem is `-` is a primitive which doesn't do argument matching.  Notice how these are the same:

```
> `-`(e1=5, e2=3)
[1] 2
> `-`(e2=5, e1=3)
[1] 2
```

From **[R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Argument-matching)**:

> This subsection applies to closures but not to **primitive functions. The latter typically ignore tags and do positional matching**, but their help pages should be consulted for exceptions, which include log, round, signif, rep and seq.int.

So in your case, you end up using `dates` as the second argument to `-` even though you attempt to specify it as the first.  By using the "Date" method for `-`, which is not a primitive, we can get it to work.

So technically, the behavior you are seeing is a feature, or perhaps a "documented inconsistency".  The part that could possibly considered a bug is that R will do a multiple dispatch to a "Date" method for `-` despite that method not supporting non-date arguments as the first argument:

```
> 1:4 - dates  # dispatches to `-.Date` despite first argument not being date
Error in `-.Date`(1:4, dates) : can only subtract from "Date" objects
```

Comment: Ah, and `lapply` puts its first argument in the first position for the supplied function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using POSIXt dates. They're a bit more flexible, for example if you wanted to add a week or year. The equivalent answer to @BrodieG using `lubridate` functionality to work with POSIXt:

```
dates <- ymd(seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+10, by='day'))
number.of.days <- 1:4

list(dates-1, dates-2, dates-3, dates-4)

lapply(number.of.days, `-.POSIXt`, e1=dates)
```

Also, how's the fishing in Philly? :)